# using refs works fine on dev mode but not working in build mode in Vue composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

this is my html:

```
<input ref="file" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" style="display:none" />
<v-btn @click="openCamera()">take photo</v-btn>
```

I'm trying to open camera(or choose a file) with a custom button:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const file = ref(null)

function openCamera() {
    file.value[0].click()
}

<script>
```

everything goes fine when I'm running the app using `yarn dev` (vite) but when I build it using `yarn build` and serve it on server the app throws this error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
```

and the `file` is null.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it does. I remove that style and they both work fine(on dev mode). but when I build it , the now visible button works fine but v-btn does not work.

Comment: Isn't it kind of weird that you are creating ref as `file = ref(null)` but later you are assuming it contains an array and trying to access its first element as `file.value[0]`? If you are assigning multiple elements same ref name (for example inside v-for), it should be created as empty array `file = ref([])`. If you have only one element with that ref name you should access it as `file.value`.

Comment: nevermind @MichalHynčica - you're right, it should be `file.value.click()` - can't understand how it would work in dev mode! I was confusing myself with `file.value.files[0]` which would be how to access the selected file - but OP is using `v-btn` to initiate the file selection :p